# Fetch API inside setInterval

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm calling chain of API calls and last api need to call multiple times. below is the function I'm calling while throwing error from the `setInterval` getting `Uncaught (in promise) Error`.

```js
function firstAPI() {
    return fetch(url);
}

function secondAPI(key) {
    return fetch(url);
}

async function dataFetch() {
    try {
        let firstAPIData = await firstAPI();

        if (!firstAPIData?.ok) {
            throw Error(firstAPIData.text());
        }

        let firstAPIResponse = await firstAPIData.json(); // response{key:'abc'}
        let
            i = 1,
            flag = 0;

        let interval = setInterval(async function () {
            if (i < 10) {
                let secondAPIData = await secondAPI(firstAPIResponse.key);

                if (!secondAPIData.ok) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    throw Error(secondAPIData.text());
                }

                let secondAPIResponse = await secondAPIData.json(); // {data:[],status:'COMPLETE'}

                if (secondAPIResponse.status == 'COMPLETE') {
                    flag = 1;
                }

                i++;

                if (flag == 1) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    throw Error('error');
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

dataFetch();
```

Comment: `fetchApi` did you mean `firstApi`?

Comment: what should give proper error response? If you expect `catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }` that is not going to happen since the setTimeout is not synchronous.

Comment: Yes, its firstApi...modified...

Comment: @epascarello, then could you please guide the best way or what to do...thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you run things in `setTimeout` or `setInterval` they are not executed synchronously like you expect it here. They get instead scheduled to be run later. Because they run later they are not in the try/catch block anymore and thus the error is uncaught.
You can read more about the event loop here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop#event_loop

In your case I would instead make a async "sleep" function:

```js
function sleep(ms){
 return new Promise ((resolve, _reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, ms)
 })
}
```

You can then do `await sleep(1000)` in your loop instead of the timeout:

```js
function firstAPI(){
    return fetch(url)
}
function secondAPI(key){
    return fetch(url)
}
async function dataFetch(){
    try{
        let firstAPIData = await firstApi();
        if(!firstAPIData?.ok){
            throw Error(firstAPIData.text())
        }
        let firstAPIResponse = await firstAPIData.json();//response{key:'abc'}
        let flag=0;
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         let secondAPIData = await secondAPI(firstAPIResponse.key)
         if(!secondAPIData.ok){
          throw Error(secondAPIData.text())
         }
         let secondAPIResponse = await secondAPIData.json();//{data:[],status:'COMPLETE'}
         if(secondAPIResponse.status == 'COMPLETE'){
          flag =1;
          throw Error('error')
          // I guess you want to return something here instead of throwing the error?
         }
         // wait 1 second (I guess you have this to not run into rate limits)
         await sleep(1000)
        }
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}
dataFetch()
```

This is not an exact representation of your code because it waits until the request and then waits 1 second again, instead of just making a new request every second and ignoring the outcome of the last request, you could get a one second timeout behaviour with `Promise.race()` if you really need that.